# sort array of divs based on types of divs from low to high in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, sorting

Below code is used to sort arrays as shown just below:

```
function sorter(a, b) {
    if((b.dataset.type === 'Recommended') && (a.dataset.type === 'Recommended'))
      return (b.dataset.type === 'Recommended') - (a.dataset.type === 'Recommended') || a.dataset.amount - b.dataset.amount;
    if((b.dataset.type === 'Featured') && (a.dataset.type === 'Featured'))
        return (b.dataset.type === 'Featured') - (a.dataset.type === 'Featured') || a.dataset.amount - b.dataset.amount;
    if((b.dataset.type === 'Special Offer') && (a.dataset.type === 'Special Offer'))
        return (b.dataset.type === 'Special Offer') - (a.dataset.type === 'Special Offer') || a.dataset.amount - b.dataset.amount;
    if((b.dataset.type === 'Christmas') && (a.dataset.type === 'Christmas'))
        return (b.dataset.type === 'Christmas') - (a.dataset.type === 'Christmas') || a.dataset.amount - b.dataset.amount;
    if((b.dataset.type === '') && (a.dataset.type === ''))
        return (b.dataset.type === '') - (a.dataset.type === '') || a.dataset.amount - b.dataset.amount;
  }
  var sortedDivs = $(".terminalpopular").toArray().sort(sorter);
```

I have sorted an array based on different types (i.e. recommended, featured, christmas and no type) labeled on the divs, as below:

```
<div class=​"terminalpopular" data-amount=​"65.95" data-type=​"Recommended">​…​</div>​
<div class=​"terminalpopular" data-amount=​"70" data-type=​"Recommended">​…​</div>​
<div class=​"terminalpopular" data-amount=​"94.95" data-type=​"Recommended">​…​</div>​
<div class=​"terminalpopular" data-amount=​"67.99" data-type=​"Featured">​…​</div>​
<div class=​"terminalpopular" data-amount=​"75" data-type=​"Featured">​…​</div>​
<div class=​"terminalpopular" data-amount=​"78" data-type=​"Christmas">​…​</div>​
<div class=​"terminalpopular" data-amount=​"84.99" data-type=​"Christmas">​…​</div>​
<div class=​"terminalpopular" data-amount=​"54.95" data-type>​…​</div>​
<div class=​"terminalpopular" data-amount=​"84.99" data-type>​…​</div>​
```

I wanted to sort it as per below (INTENDED RESULT):

```
<div class=​"terminalpopular" data-amount=​"65.95" data-type=​"Recommended">​…​</div>​
<div class=​"terminalpopular" data-amount=​"67.99" data-type=​"Featured">​…​</div>​
<div class=​"terminalpopular" data-amount=​"78" data-type=​"Christmas">​…​</div>​
<div class=​"terminalpopular" data-amount=​"70" data-type=​"Recommended">​…​</div>
<div class=​"terminalpopular" data-amount=​"75" data-type=​"Featured">​…​</div>​
<div class=​"terminalpopular" data-amount=​"84.99" data-type=​"Christmas">​…​</div>​​
<div class=​"terminalpopular" data-amount=​"94.95" data-type=​"Recommended">​…​</div>​
<div class=​"terminalpopular" data-amount=​"54.95" data-type>​…​</div>​
<div class=​"terminalpopular" data-amount=​"84.99" data-type>​…​</div>​
```

Demonstration in words:

Can you suggest that how can I sort the array based on types in such way. i.e. Recommended have values of 84, 74, 64 and we have Featured type as well and having values of 78, 68, 88. Can we sort it in such form: 64 (recommended), 68 (featured), 74(recommended), 78 (featured), 84(recommended), 88 (featured) etc and son on ?

[image]

Comment: so you want to sort the list based on data-amount?

Comment: if you want a library that you can just throw in, http://listjs.com/ is pretty good

Comment: Actually, I wanted to sort it on the Price from LOW TO HIGH for each type of divs (i.e. recommended, featured, special offer, Christmas and no type). Recommended has higher priority followed by other types. i.e. It should show LOW in recommended followed by LOW price for Featured, then followed by LOW price for Special Offer if any and then, followed by LOW value for Christmas and at the end LOW to HIGH for no type divs. I hope, you got it.

Comment: *Recommended has higher priority followed by other types* If this is true, should `94.95` come second?

Comment: Its like: LOW to HIGH for individual types. Take first low from first group i.e. recommended, you are done. Now, check LOW in featured, and you are done. Now, check, LOW in Special Offer and you are done and Check, LOW for Christmas and you are done and So on. Now, again, check 2nd Recommended LOW value and so on .. . . . . .

Comment: So to simply say, sort elements that have type value followed by elements without type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a sample of the kind of arrangement you wanted.

In my understanding, using 1 sort function will be difficult here, so have broken the problems in stages. Due to this, following solution might take many extra iteration.

```js
var emptyList = '__EMPTY__';
function processElements() {
  var list = $('.terminalpopular');
  var clone = list.clone();
  
  var groupedList = createGroups(clone);
  var sortedGroups = sortGroups(groupedList);
  var arrangedList = arrangeElements(sortedGroups);
  
  list.parent().empty().append(arrangedList)
}

// Create groups based on type
function createGroups(list) {
  return Array.from(list).reduce(function(p, c){
    var type = c.dataset.type || emptyList;
    p[type] = p[type] || [];
    p[type].push(c);
    return p;
  }, Object.create(null));
}

// Sort each group by amount
function sortGroups(list) {
  function sortFn(a, b) {
    return Number(a.dataset.amount) - Number(b.dataset.amount);
  }
  for (var k in list) {
    list[k].sort(sortFn);
  }
  return list;
}

// Rearrange elements based on index
function arrangeElements(sortedList) {
  var list = [];
  var max = Math.max.apply(null, Object.keys(sortedList)
              .filter(x => x !== emptyList)
              .map(x => sortedList[x].length)
            );
  for(var i = 0; i< max; i++) {
    list = list.concat(Object.keys(sortedList)
              .filter(x => x !== emptyList)
              .map(x => sortedList[x][i])
            );
  }           
  
  list = list.concat(sortedList[emptyList]);
  return list;
}

// This is only for display purpose
function displayValue() {
  $('.terminalpopular').each(function(i, el) {
    $(el).text($(el).data('amount'));
    if ($(el).data('type')) {
      $(el).addClass('highlight')
    }
  })
}

displayValue();
processElements();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="terminalpopular" data-amount="65.95" data-type="Recommended">​…​</div>​
  <div class="terminalpopular" data-amount="70" data-type="Recommended">​…​</div>​
  <div class="terminalpopular" data-amount="94.95" data-type="Recommended">​…​</div>​
  <div class="terminalpopular" data-amount="67.99" data-type="Featured">​…​</div>​
  <div class="terminalpopular" data-amount="75" data-type="Featured">​…​</div>​
  <div class="terminalpopular" data-amount="78" data-type="Christmas">​…​</div>​
  <div class="terminalpopular" data-amount="84.99" data-type="Christmas">​…​</div>​
  <div class="terminalpopular" data-amount="54.95" data-type>​…​</div>​
  <div class="terminalpopular" data-amount="84.99" data-type>​…​</div>​
</div>
```

Comment: <div class=​"terminalpopular" data-amount=​"78" data-type=​"Christmas">​…​</div>​ . Christmas should come third. Please, check my intended results as given in question.

Comment: INTENDED RESULT: 
===============
data-amount=​"65.95" data-type=​"Recommended" (recom: 1st low) 
data-amount=​"67.99" data-type=​"Featured" (feat: 1st low)
data-amount=​"78" data-type=​"Christmas" (christ: 1st low)
data-amount=​"70" data-type=​"Recommended" (recom: 2nd low)
data-amount=​"75" data-type=​"Featured" (feat: 2nd low)
data-amount=​"84.99" data-type=​"Christmas" (christ: 2nd low)
data-amount=​"94.95" data-type=​"Recommended" (recom: third low)
data-amount=​"54.95" data-type (noType: 1st low)
data-amount=​"84.99" data-type (noType: 2nd low)

Comment: Yes, Consider groups based on types and take first LOW value from each group and append; with No type at end in the form of LOW to HIGH.

Comment: If you can have eye on both Given Divs and Intended result Divs, you will get the whole idea. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, I checked it as well. Nice work, done. Thanks Rajesh. You are awesome.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sort()` method and first sort by data `type` property and then by `amount`.

```js
var sorted = $(".parent > div").sort(function(a, b) {
  return ($(b).data('type') != '') - ($(a).data('type') != '') || +$(a).data('amount') - +$(b).data('amount')
})

$('.parent').html(sorted)

// Just for demo
$('.parent > div').each(function() {
  $(this).text($(this).data('amount'))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="terminalpopular" data-amount="65.95" data-type="Recommended">…</div>
  <div class="terminalpopular" data-amount="70" data-type="Recommended">…</div>
  <div class="terminalpopular" data-amount="94.95" data-type="Recommended">…</div>
  <div class="terminalpopular" data-amount="67.99" data-type="Featured">…</div>
  <div class="terminalpopular" data-amount="75" data-type="Featured">…</div>
  <div class="terminalpopular" data-amount="78" data-type="Christmas">…</div>
  <div class="terminalpopular" data-amount="84.99" data-type="Christmas">…</div>
  <div class="terminalpopular" data-amount="54.95" data-type>…</div>
  <div class="terminalpopular" data-amount="84.99" data-type>…</div>
</div>
```

**Update** Create object with keys based on types and value as array of elements with those types, then sort those values based on amount then loop each object property and add to parent element.

```js
var obj = {}
$('.parent > div').each(function() {
  var type = $(this).data('type');
  if (type == '') type = 'empty';
  if (!obj[type]) obj[type] = [];
  obj[type].push($(this))
})

for (var i in obj) obj[i].sort(function(a, b) {
  return $(a).data('amount') - $(b).data('amount')
})

$('.parent').empty();
var max = Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(r, e) {
  var l = obj[e].length;
  if (r == null || l > obj[r].length) r = e
  return r;
}, null)

obj[max].forEach(function(e, i) {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(k) {
    if (k != 'empty' && obj[k][i]) $('.parent').append(obj[k][i])
  })
})

$('.parent').append(...obj['empty'])

$('.parent > div').each(function() {
  $(this).text($(this).data('amount') + ' ' + $(this).data('type'))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="terminalpopular" data-amount="65.95" data-type="Recommended">…</div>
  <div class="terminalpopular" data-amount="70" data-type="Recommended">…</div>
  <div class="terminalpopular" data-amount="94.95" data-type="Recommended">…</div>
  <div class="terminalpopular" data-amount="67.99" data-type="Featured">…</div>
  <div class="terminalpopular" data-amount="75" data-type="Featured">…</div>
  <div class="terminalpopular" data-amount="78" data-type="Christmas">…</div>
  <div class="terminalpopular" data-amount="84.99" data-type="Christmas">…</div>
  <div class="terminalpopular" data-amount="54.95" data-type>…</div>
  <div class="terminalpopular" data-amount="84.99" data-type>…</div>
</div>
```

Comment: <div class=​"terminalpopular" data-amount=​"78" data-type=​"Christmas">​…​</div>​ . Christmas should come third. Please, check my intended results as given in question.

Comment: INTENDED RESULT: 
===============
data-amount=​"65.95" data-type=​"Recommended" (recom: 1st low) 
data-amount=​"67.99" data-type=​"Featured" (feat: 1st low)
data-amount=​"78" data-type=​"Christmas" (christ: 1st low)
data-amount=​"70" data-type=​"Recommended" (recom: 2nd low)
data-amount=​"75" data-type=​"Featured" (feat: 2nd low)
data-amount=​"84.99" data-type=​"Christmas" (christ: 2nd low)
data-amount=​"94.95" data-type=​"Recommended" (recom: third low)
data-amount=​"54.95" data-type (noType: 1st low)
data-amount=​"84.99" data-type (noType: 2nd low)

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. I am trying it with all groups I have and update my code accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. It is working like a charm. I extended it and make it according to my needs. You are great. Thanks mate.